# HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed as a respond

Tags: node.js, rest, curl, jira

I try https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues with my own credentials

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X PUT --data {see below} -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31
```

but it throws an error as `HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed`

what can be the problem?

Comment: Did you paste the body of the request i.e {see below} part?

Comment: yes I pase the part by deleting new line and white space characters from it

Comment: What's your JIRA Version?

Comment: the version is `4.2.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document that you mentioned clearly said that, it's applicable for JIRA 5.0 and later. So most likely that old version of JIRA doesn't have this method :-)

As far as I can remember JIRA 4.2.1 has Alpha version of REST API thus if you really wants to use REST API better to consider upgrading your JIRA to the latest version. I believe this call is not supported for your current version.